# issue in seeing the created input from execcommand('copy') jquery

Tags: jquery, copy, execcommand

I am using IE11 and using the following code to copy data.

```
<input type="button" class="btn" id="CopyIDs" value="Copy All IDs"/>

 $(document).on('click', '#CopyIDs', function () {
        GridData = "test any data"
        var $temp = $("<input>");
        $("body").append($temp);
        $temp.val(GridData).select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        $temp.remove();
        alert("Data Copied To Clipboard Successfully")
    });
```

it is working normally but I have an issue that I can see the created input that contains the copied data then it disappeared in one second.

I don't want to see it on the application .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

$('form').append($temp); instead of $("body").append($temp);

Thanks